# pandas - single column to multiple columns (getting key length error)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having trouble with a thought process on a single to multiple columns using pandas. I have a main column that could have up to ten words separated by commas. I only have eight columns to split out these words to (no more).

I'm Currently using the code below to split out words into multiple columns. This code works as long as I know exactly how many words is in the longest cell. Example: In this case below, one of the cells in the original file will have exactly eight words in order for this to work properly. Otherwise, I will get an error ( Columns must be same length as key ). In testing, I have found that I must have the same number of columns needed to split the longest cell with the same number of words. No more, no less.

```
df[['column1','column2','column3','column4','column5','column6','column7','column8']] = 
df['main'].str.split(',',expand=True)
```

What I'd like to see happen is a way to not worry about how many words are in the cells of the main column.  If longest cell contains 6 words then split them out to 6 columns. If longest cell contains 8 words then split them out to 8 columns. If longest cell contains 10 words then drop last two words and split the rest out using 8 columns.

About the original file main column. I will not know how many words exist in each of the cells.  I just have 8 columns so the first eight (if that many) get the honor of splitting to a column. The rest of the words (if any) will get dropped.

Question, Why do I need to have the exact amount of columns in the code above if my longest cell with words doesn't exceed that of my columns? I'm not understanding something.

Any help with the logic would be appreciated.

```
cols = df[['column1','column2','column3','column4','column5','column6','column7','column8']]
df2 = df['main'].str.split(',',expand=True, n=8) 
#df = df.assign(**df2.set_axis(cols[:df2.shape[1]], axis=1))

#-------
if 0 in df2.columns:
   df['column1']= np.where(df2[0].isnull(), df['column1'], df2[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `n=8` and then split the last column

```
df2 = df['main'].str.split(',', expand=True, n=8)
df = df.assign(**df2.set_axis(df.columns[:df2.shape[1]], axis=1))


df['column8'] = df['column8'].str.split(',').str[0]
```

You can use a list of labels instead df.columns if you don't want save the result in the first df2.shape[1] columns of df

Comment: Thank You Ansev for helping me with this issue.  I have never used the (Shape) statement before and I hope I'm applying everything correctly.  I made an edit above to show you the change code I'm currently using.  In printing, (df2.head(30) shows correctly the columns with words. However, I'm receiving an error on the df.assign line you suggested. Error Reads - KeyError(('nan','nan','nan','nan','nan','nan','nan','nan')).  When steping thru F8 - I can see the cols dataframe shows columns 1-8 all with nan value in the cells.  Could this be some of the problem?

Comment: Hey Ansev, just an update.  With your logic performing a split column to secondary df2 dataframe the words populated the df2 columns correctly.  Then I did a df2 column check exist, if column exist then copy values back to df columns 1-8. Once completed, I replaced the nan with ''(blank-space) to delete nan from columns. I know there is a better way to perform what I'm trying to do.  I will read up on your df.assign / shape statements line that you provided me and see if i can get it working.  I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Yes, I can put together something for you.

Comment: Ansev, I have a sample for your review. Please let me know what you think. If you have any questions just let me know.          shorturl.at/ivzI1        This link will contain an excel file. Sheet1 contains the data, sheet2 (Code) contains the code currently using. Please let me know if any troubles receiving the file.